# Why my ng-options are not corrected generated?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have json data generated in server. Data generated are  :

```
[
   {"identifier":1,"data":{"name":"One"}},
   {"identifier":2,"data":{"name":"Two"}}
]
```

I want to create the following select :

```
<select  ng-model="mydata.identifier">
<option value="">Please choose option</option>
<option value="**0**">One</option>
<option value="**1**">Two</option>
</select>
```

Here is my code :

Angularjs controller:

```
$scope.initMyData =  function(){
    $http.get('getData')
    .success(function (data) {
                $scope.alldata= data;

    }); 
};
```

My html

```
 <select ng-model="mydata.identifier" ng-options="data.data.name for data in alldata">
          <option value="">Please choose option</option>
    </select>
```

Why value of my option are not correct ? What's not good with my code ?
Thanks

Comment: `data.name as data.identifier for data in alldata`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<select ng-model="mydata.identifier" ng-options="data.data.name for data in alldata.data">
      <option value="">Please choose option</option>
</select>
```

Array should be like this

```
[  
   {"identifier":1,"data":{"name":"One"}},
   {"identifier":2,"data":{"name":"Two"}}
];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/fuxecexadiya/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing closing braces for one.

```
[
  {"identifier":1,"data":{"name":"One"},
  {"identifier":2,"data":{"name":"Two"}
]
```

Should be

```
[
  {"identifier":1,"data":{"name":"One"}},
  {"identifier":2,"data":{"name":"Two"}}
]
```

Comment: You're right i've edited the post. I was mistaken with copy paste

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. You have missed 1 closing brace `}` at end of data object in data.
2. You need to write your `ng-options` based on *object.data* format. E.g. `value.data`

`<select ng-model="mydata.identifier" ng-options="value.data.name for value in allData">
      <option value="">Please choose option</option>
</select>`

I have created a sample fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1wtos7r/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` annotation to tell angular what value to bind to `ng-model`

```
<select ng-model="mydata.identifier" 
      ng-options="data.identifier as data.data.name for data in alldata">
   <option value="">Please choose option</option>
</select>
```

[Angular API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i get this on html.It's not was i want to display. <option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>